# React native react-navigation drawerLabel truncated on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

When a I use the DrawerNavigator from react-navigation module, the drawerLabel were truncated on Android. I have no problem on IOs.

Capture Menu on IOS

[image]

Capture Menu on Android

[image]

**Exemple of my Home Screen** :

```html
...

export default class Home extends Component  {

  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
      return(
        <Icon
           color={tintColor}
           name='home'
          type='entypo' />
      )
    }
  }
  
  constructor(){
  ...
```

**My index.js** :

```html
...
const NavigatorApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Home: {screen: Home  },
  ...
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => NavigatorApp);
```

**My environnement** :

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.46.4

react-navigation: ^1.0.0-beta.11